# Groovy: How to run .groovy script in silent mode?

Tags: groovy

How to run .groovy script in silent mode ?

Comment: What do you mean?  You want to hide any `println` statements? Are you on windows?

Comment: in my script i dont use any prinln functions, but when i run script the console window opened and after when script finished work, console window is closing. this is not good, because i want make this script as windows service or run it by scheduler in silently mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can use.

```
    groovy myScript.groovy --silent
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [Windows Installer](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download) contains `groovyw.exe` which should do what you want.

Never tried it though :-/